# state contract not change after execute ContractUpgradeFlow

Tags: corda

I try to upgrade contract following this article https://docs.corda.net/contract-upgrade.html
then after execute ContractUpgradeFlow no error but when query vault it seem state still belong to old contract.

In table it's already insert to node_contract_upgrades

[image: table = node_contract_upgrades]

But when query state from vault I still got old contract and if I make transaction with (old state + new contract) it will show contract constraint

```
Flow Internal Error : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection: Contract constraints failed for th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.contracts.CustomerContractV01, transaction: 418A9A1562A1A7F3C465EC2CC5DDEFB83F5D9C71269EDF83BFBA1094274F926F
```

Here my client.kt for run flow upgrade

```
       <pre>`<pre>fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        UpgradeContractClient().main(args)
    }

    /**
     *  A utility demonstrating the contract upgrade process.
     *  In this case, we are upgrading the states' contracts, but not the states
     *  themselves.
     **/
    private class UpgradeContractClient {
        companion object {
            val logger: Logger = loggerFor<UpgradeContractClient>()
        }

        fun main(args: Array<String>) {


            val clientDs = CordaRPCClient(parse("localhost:10009"))
            val dsProxy = clientDs.start("user1", "test").proxy

            val clientPah = CordaRPCClient(parse("localhost:10008"))
            val pahProxy = clientPah.start("user1", "test").proxy

            // Authorise the upgrade of all the State instances using OldContract.
            println("Doing Authorise")
            listOf(dsProxy, pahProxy).forEach { proxy ->
                // Extract all the unconsumed State instances from the vault.
                val stateAndRefs = proxy.vaultQuery(CustomerStateV01::class.java).states
                println("Found customerState=${stateAndRefs.size} for node : ${proxy.nodeInfo()}")

                // Run the upgrade flow for each one.
                stateAndRefs.filter { stateAndRef ->
                    stateAndRef.state.contract == CustomerContractV01.CONTRACT_ID
                }.forEach { stateAndRef ->
                    proxy.startFlowDynamic(
                            ContractUpgradeFlow.Authorise::class.java,
                            stateAndRef,
                            CustomerContractV02::class.java).returnValue.getOrThrow()
                }

                println("Finished")

            }
            Thread.sleep(5000)

            // Initiate the upgrade of all the State instances using OldContract.
            println("Doing Initiate")
            dsProxy.vaultQuery(CustomerStateV01::class.java).states
                    .filter { stateAndRef ->
                        stateAndRef.state.contract == CustomerContractV01.CONTRACT_ID
                    }
                    .forEach { stateAndRef ->
                        dsProxy.startFlowDynamic(
                                ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate::class.java,
                                stateAndRef,
                                CustomerContractV02::class.java)
                    }

            // Log all the State instances in the vault to show they are using NewContract.
            dsProxy.vaultQuery(CustomerStateV01::class.java).states.forEach { println("${it.state}") }
            dsProxy.vaultQuery(CustomerStateV01::class.java).states.forEach { println("${it.state.contract}") }
        }}`
```

And here my contractV02

```
class CustomerContractV02 : UpgradedContract<CustomerStateV01, CustomerStateV01>{
override val legacyContract: ContractClassName
    get() = CustomerContractV01.CONTRACT_ID


override fun upgrade(state: CustomerStateV01): CustomerStateV01 {
    return state
}
```

What I expect is state with old contract should do transaction with new contract or I misunderstood of concept?

Comment: How are you querying the states from the vault when you are checking whether they use the old contract? Note that the contract upgrade process consumes the states with the old contract to create new states with the new contract. Make sure you are not querying for the old states.

Comment: My upgrade just want new contract with old state so I use this for query dsProxy.vaultQuery(CustomerStateV01::class.java).states.forEach { println("${it.state.contract}") } then all CustomerStateV01 still using CustomerContractV01

Comment: You are executing the `ContractUpgradeFlow.Initiate` flows asynchronously. Can you try inserting a 10 second sleep (`Thread.sleep(10000)`) before the final vault query to give the flows time to execute?

Comment: No luck, still got state with oldcontract

Comment: Still got th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.contracts.CustomerContractV01 when vaultQuery with CustomerStateV01 and vault_states still have 1 row with CustomerContractV01

Comment: Can you mention which constraint you were using before upgrading was it hash constraint or zone whitelist constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As my investigation. It's because of replace old_contract.jar with new_contract.jar make contract's constraint, Then Corda don't let contract upgrade flow. So my solution is update network parameter before execute ContractUpgradeFlow.